# Javascript regex to validate received search string for MySQL full-text search

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex, full-text-search

I need to validate, if a entered search string used for a full-text search (boolean mode) on a MySQL database is valid.

The minimum word length (ft_min_word_len) has been set to "2" and only the following operators are allowed to be used: +, -, ", *, (, )

The following validation rules are given:

- it may contain several valid words separated by a blank
- valid words are containing at least two characters matching the following character set: `[^+\s\-\>\<\(\)\~\*\:\"\&\|]`

  - no whitespaces, no asterisk, no parentheses, no plus sign, no minus sign, no double quotes
- words may have either a leading plus sign or a leading minus sign
- words may have a trailing asterisk
- a phrase may be enclosed by double quotes

  - plus and minus signs enclosed by double quotes won´t be interpreted as operators
  - the enclosed phrase may have either a leading plus sign or a leading minus sign
- words may be enclosed by parentheses

  - the parenthesized words must not have any leading operators
  - the left parenthesis may have either a leading plus sign or a leading minus sign

Valid search string examples that must pass the regex:

```
'word1 word2 word3 word4 word5'
'+word1 +word2 word3 word4 -word5'
'+word1 +"word2 word3 word4" -word5'
'+word1 +"word2+word3 word4" -word5'
'+word1 +"word2*word3 word4" -word5'
'+word1 +(word2 word3 word4) -word5'
'+word1 +(word2 word3* word4*) -word5'
```

Invalid search string examples that must not pass the regex:

```
'w word2 word3 word4 word5'
'wo*rd2 wo+rd3 wor(d)4 "word5'
'word1+ word2+ word3 word4 -word5'
'+word1 +"word2 word3 word4 -word5'
'+word1 +(word2 word3 word4 -word5'
'+word1 +(+word2 -word3 -word4) -word5'
```

I created a regex which works pretty well, but it´s quite long and the same regex for the words is used several times, because words my be enclosed by quotes or parentheses:

```
/^((?:[+\-]?(?:(?:[^+\s\-\>\<\(\)\~\*\:\"\&\|]{2,}\*?|(?:"(?:[^"\s]{2,}[ ]*)+"))|\((?:(?:[^+\s\-\>\<\(\)\~\*\:\"\&\|]{2,}\*?|(?:"(?:[^"\s]{2,}[ ]*)+"))[ ]*)+\))(?:[ ]+|$))+)$/
```

You may test the regex at regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/lA3vG4/4

I´m no regex expert, so I´d like to know, if there´s a more simple regex that works for Javascript.

**EDIT: replaced single whitespace characters by \s, thanks to Rick James for this hint**

**EDIT2: update of reserved characters for MyISAM FULLTEXT. Thanks again to Rick James.**

Comment: What are the validation rules for a valid `String`?

Comment: I edited my initial post. Hopefully it´s more precise now.

Comment: MyISAM's FULLTEXT?  Or InnoDB's?  MyISAM, by default, avoids `+ -><()~*:""&|`.  InnoDB uses a file, I think.

Comment: You´re right about `+ -><()~*"`, because they are all operators. I haven´t found anything about the characters `:&|`. Do you have a source where they are mentioned?

Comment: BTW: MyISAM's FULLTEXT

Comment: I found a corresponding section in the MySQL reference manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_boolean_syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider simplifying by replacing whitespace tests with `[[:space:]]`.  (I don't know if Javascript understands that notation.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. There´s the character `\s` in Javascript for this purpose.